# Converting JSON from URL to CSV with PHP

Tags: php, json, csv

When I run the code below it results in the first row in a long list of columns containing only the text *Array*.

I've used `$decoded = json_decode($json_file, true);` to indicate that I want arrays instead of objects so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Should I be using bracket or arrow notation somewhere to specify that I want the array values?

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('https://fakeurl.com&contentType=json', false);

$decoded = json_decode($json_file, true);

$fp = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
foreach($decoded as $comment) {
    fputcsv($fp, $comment);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Here is a small snippet of the JSON. It looks like this all the way through:

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "columns": [{
            "name": "clientId",
            "value": "1839",
            "type": "xs:int",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignId",
            "value": "25646",
            "type": "xs:int",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignStatus",
            "value": "Live",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignName",
            "value": "Template Donation Litle",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignExportName",
            "value": "Template Donation Litle",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "description",
            "value": "/donate/template/Litle",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }]
    }, {
        "columns": [{
            "name": "clientId",
            "value": "1839",
            "type": "xs:int",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignId",
            "value": "25812",
            "type": "xs:int",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignStatus",
            "value": "Live",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignName",
            "value": "Monthly Only",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "campaignExportName",
            "value": "Monthly Only",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }, {
            "name": "description",
            "value": "A donation receipt will be emailed to the address you submitted. This donation is tax-deductible to the fullest extent of the law.",
            "type": "xs:string",
            "format": ""
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON data please?...

Comment: Do a `print_r($decoded);` so we can see what `$decoded` actually contains. We can't guess.

Comment: Hey @War10ck and Magnus I've added a small portion of the JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is much deeper and the values need to be extracted:

```
foreach($decoded['rows'] as $row) {
    $values = array_column($row['columns'], 'value');
    fputcsv($fp, $values);
}
```

If you want the names/headers in the first row then you need to do this before the loop:

```
$headers = array_column($decoded['rows'][0]['columns'], 'name');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
```

Comment: array_column expects parameter 1 to be an array but null is given

Comment: https://3v4l.org/GiGmH  
Then the JSON didn't decode, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: But I used this decode function: $decoded = json_decode($json_file, true);

Comment: Hey thanks man I play around with what was in the foreach loop but I managed to figure it out. Thanks!